# What's the difference in performance when using instance variables v/s anonymous classes?

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

My program has the following code:

```
List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>> listVariable=new Gson().fromJson(data.getStringData(),new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>>>(){}.getType());
```

Instead I can use

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String jsonData=data.getStringData();
Type tt=new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>>>(){}.getType();
List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>> listVariable=gson.fromJson(jsonData,tt);
```

Two questions:

1. How do these compare in performance?
2. Is there any way to save the lengthy type(`List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>>`) to a variable and use it wherever i need it as the type?

Comment: Your title makes no sense. One is a *field*, the other is a *class*. Asking for comparison of apples and cars makes no sense.

Comment: 1. Unlikely you'll see any difference. 2. Sure, save the `TypeReference` anywhere you like.

Comment: @shmosel I believe OP is asking for the Java equivalent of the C `typedef`, so you can assign a short typename to the long type declaration, e.g. `typedef MyList List<HashMap<String,SampleClass>>` so you can then use `MyList listVariable=gson.fromJson(jsonData,tt);`. The answer is that Java doesn't have that.

Comment: Since the JVM still need to create the same instance and keep the reference somewhere (just without giving it to you), the difference would be minimal. The two are still using instances. Just one is inline, without a declaration.

Comment: Length _per se_ is not a bad thing. What is the engineering advantage you expect to gain from typing fewer keystrokes? Remember that having the type information in the declarations increases readability in that a maintainer need not look around for what a "typedef" means. One knows right away what the generics assertions are. You really shouldn't sweep type assertions under the rug because they document valuable type relationships as well as enforce them.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in the second version is that you are creating some "intermediate" variables. So theoretically, when you put those statements into a method, the minimal overhead for "having" local variables on the stack kicks in.

But rest assured, they do not matter in the context of these calls that probably do heavy string parsing and object creation already.

So the answer is: there is no difference; you solely pick that version that works better for you (and your team) regarding **readability** and maintenance efforts.

Beyond that: Java performance does most often **not** depend on such subtle details.